# Android Emulator Error EAX=e0000011 EBX=00000000 ECX=00000000 EDX=00000000

Tags: android, performance, android-emulator, android-emulator-plugin

Recently, when I was starting application for debugging on android 4.4.2 emulator, I've got such error

```
[2014-11-25 14:08:35 - Emulator] EAX=e0000011 EBX=00000000 ECX=00000000 EDX=00000000
[2014-11-25 14:08:35 - Emulator] ESI=00020800 EDI=007bb000 EBP=00bdf003 ESP=0072ae00
[2014-11-25 14:08:35 - Emulator] EIP=006d4053 EFL=00000002 [-------] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
[2014-11-25 14:08:35 - Emulator] ES =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
[2014-11-25 14:08:35 - Emulator] CS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09b00 DPL=0 CS32 [-RA]
[2014-11-25 14:08:35 - Emulator] SS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
[2014-11-25 14:08:35 - Emulator] DS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
[2014-11-25 14:08:35 - Emulator] FS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
[2014-11-25 14:08:35 - Emulator] GS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
[2014-11-25 14:08:35 - Emulator] LDT=0000 00000000 00000000 00008200 DPL=0 LDT
[2014-11-25 14:08:35 - Emulator] TR =0020 00001000 00000067 00008b00 DPL=0 TSS32-busy
[2014-11-25 14:08:35 - Emulator] GDT=     00678180 0000001f
[2014-11-25 14:08:35 - Emulator] IDT=     00000000 00000000
[2014-11-25 14:08:35 - Emulator] CR0=e0000011 CR2=00000000 CR3=00719000 CR4=00000000
[2014-11-25 14:08:35 - Emulator] DR0=00000000 DR1=00000000 DR2=00000000 DR3=00000000 
[2014-11-25 14:08:35 - Emulator] DR6=ffff0ff0 DR7=00000000
```

[2014-11-25 14:08:35 - Emulator] Error accepting connection, aborting

And if somebody knows, what shold be done to prevent them in future development projects?
Thanks for help.

Comment: Have you tried assigning more RAM to the Emulator?

Comment: @AzzaFazza3515 I've allocated 1024 mb. Sometimes it happens anyway...